# Java/Android: Facebook SDK login two ways and no one work

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I have a problem with facebook login in android application. I've found two ways to do it: one old and deprecated, and the new one. When I've implemented deprecated, during testing all worked fine, while not having official facebook application installed. After I've installed it, pre-check-in tells that my application is misconfigured.
When I've implemented the second way, it also didn't work. It even didn't start session.

Link to the tutorials:
Old way: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/
New way: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

And also one thing, when I've added facebook projects to my workspace, the android suppot libraries in my sdk and in facebook sdk where not identical, so I've resolved it by changing facebook's one to those from Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your key hash correctly in order for native SSO to work.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/13499901/931354